# Changable Text update slowdown in andEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I have problem with ChangableText, I'm using it to display current score.

But it has problem, because there is big slowdown while it is getting updated.
BUT, after reaching 90 points, there is no lags anymore while updating text...(only those first 9x10 points)

Any Solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create changeable text try to specify all the numbers you will use.

For example:

```
ChangeableText Scoretext = new ChangeableText(100, 100, font, "0123456789", vertexBufferObjectManager);
```

Comment: This class is no longer in Andengine.